# Tabbaritem unclickable behind uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

i've created a custom tabbar, where i've added a UIButton to the the main view on top of the tabbar. The problem is that the UIButton is on top of existing tabbaritem and therefor it is not switching to the viewcontroller that it should. Is there a way to present the UIButton behind the UITabBarItem, so it will go to the viewcontroller and still show the uibutton image?

Comment: Why do you want a `UIButton` behind the tab bar item?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `UIButton` if it is not supposed to be interactive? Why not just use an `UIImageView` or more generically a `UIView`?

Comment: It is suppose to be interactive, by changing the button image when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UIImageView instead of a `UIButton`. Set the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and implement the `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` method to see when the user tapped on the tab. Then just change the image in your `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set image in UITabBar, You can use

```
UITabBarItem *tab1 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
tab1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

If you need button to set in UITabBar, You can use

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
tab1 addSubView:button];
```